# What is the maximum takeoff weight allowed for a part 103 ultralight?

Tags: faa-regulations, ultralight

What is the max takeoff weight (MTOW) for a part 103 vertical takeoff (VTOL) ultralight?

And is the value peak or continuous limit?

Answer (score 3):

[14 CFR 103.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/103.1)

The FAA currently does not discriminate between "VTOL" and "normal" ultralight aircraft, nor between gas-powered or electric. The aircraft, if powered, cannot weigh more than 254lbs "empty" weight excluding floats and safety equipment that deploys in an emergency situation.

I'm not sure what you mean by "peak limit" or "continuous operation". The aircraft, when weighed without liquid fuel, must be less than 254lbs. It can carry up to 5 US-gallons of fuel (which can add up to 30lbs).

There is no limit to the MTOW for the aircraft though, it can carry a 400lb individual if you can make it fly, but it can't carry more than 1 person. So if the aircraft weighed 253lbs, you were 400, fuel is 30 that is 683lbs and still legal under Part 103. (Depending on how liberally you want to apply the "single occupant" rule, you may try to squeak your 200lb Mastiff aboard as well)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "gross weight" limit as far as I can find in the regulations.  I think the thing you need to be concerned about is Power off stall speed.  The regulations do state a 25 knot limit on power off stall which has to do with wing loading.  If you have a high wing loading (high weight to wing area ratio) then your stall speed will be higher.
So the question is what is YOUR Gross Weight based on your wing area, weight and lift coefficient and air density.  So you need to "work backwards" with the stall speed formula to determine the gross weight for your aircraft.
SkyClimber